# Setting up the image for my Website in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

I followed facebooks guidelines to embed a Like button inside my website.
The website has Flash in it so I always get this in my facebook when I do a 'Like'.
I would like to set the picture to something else.

That's what I am getting. Get Adobe flash player image

[image]

Comment: Show us the HTML code of the page where the image and flash is based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your head tags:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://image.jpg"/>
```

change `http://image.jpg` to the URL of your image.

EDIT:

I can't really see whats wrong here, but we could always try hiding the flash content from Facebook.

Knowing the facebook useragent (`facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`)

Add this code to the top of your page:

```
$fb_ua="facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)";

$user_ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Now replace your flash object html with this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1024" height="768" id="Israel-Iran" align="center">
                <param name="movie" value="Israel-Iran.swf?>" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Israel-Iran.swf" width="1024" height="768">
                    <param name="movie" value="Israel-Iran.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <?php if($user_ua!=$fb_ua){?><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
}?>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

Comment: I have this: <meta property="og:image" content="http://voices-of-peace.com/peaceLogo.jpg" /> which doesn't show up.. The Image aspect ratio is nearly 1:1

Comment: Try removing the `<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />`

Comment: Why is your `type` set to movie? try a different image, possibly a smaller one. Also, the images are cached, so you need to refresh the cache to make sure it really wasn't the above suggested.

Comment: Try this in your head tags: `<link rel="image_src" href="http://voices-of-peace.com/peaceLogo.jpg"/>`

Comment: set type to WebSite, resized the image to 100x100, cleared cache. added the link rel attribute, I still get the adobe image

Comment: It is just like removing that line. I already removed that a href completely and bluntly, but it still gets that very same image I guess from the adobe website.

Comment: Do you get a better result ? I cleared all my cache in Firefox

Comment: no no @Ted. When I say cache, I mean the cache Facebook store on their side, not your browser cache. I know there is a way for developers to clear this, but I have no idea how to do so. I just tried sharing your link, and I don't even get any picture at all(not even the "get flash player" pic...). It crawls it, but doesn't seem to find a picture..

Comment: I used the Linter tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug   I guess it was a cache issue after all.  Thank!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

.. and enter your URL

Comment: If you check you can see there og:image pointing at a peaceLogo.jpg, which won't show up

Comment: Did you add the og tag **after** testing this out in Facebook without it? Facebook will cache the image if you did.